# Optimizar tablas en Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buenos días, estoy modificando una app donde se requiere el acceso a diferentes tipos de usuario, la app tiene una tabla para cada tipo de usuario (si funciona la app) pero si se crea N tipos de usuarios se tendría que crear N tablas lo cual no veo tan factible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero colocar solo una tabla **usuarios** como en la siguiente imagen, el problema está en que no se como desmenuzarlo para que pueda hacer las mismas referencias en la tabla **artículos**

Agradezco mucho que me puedan orientar, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: las relaciones articulos usuarios como son? porque en la tabla articulos tenes siempre muchos usuarios que hacen distintas cosas?? o uno solo esta completo y el resto en null?

Answer (score 0):

La tabla `artuculos` solo requiere de una FK que seria la FK de la tabla `usuarios` y usuarios requiere de un FK correspondiente a la tabla `tipoUsuario` tabla que tendrás que crear la cual almacenara todos los tipos de usuarios que se te ocurran un ejemplo muy básico es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que te aclare saludos;

Comment: en realidad habria que preguntarle a op si esto es correcto.. un articulo tiene un vendedor, un comprador, un admin (todo segun el diseño que mostro arriba), con el ejemplo que estas pasando, toda esa info se pierde...

Comment: Explico un poco el asunto, tengo la tabla articulo y con los datos (descripción, marca, cantidad) eso los da de alta un vendedor, en la misma tabla tiene el campo (tiempo de entrega) eso lo actualiza un usuario de compras y por ultimo existe el campo precio (lo actualiza un usuario administrador). Para cada acción se necesita el nombre de quien agregó o actualizó alguna información por lo que necesito hacer las referencias para cada tipo de usuario.